# How to separate fields from methods in logical manner?

Tags: design, object-oriented-design

In my application I have entities like employee, client etc. Each of these have methods AddEmployee, RemoveEmployee, AddClient, RemoveClient. I don't want to keep fields like EmployeeName, EmployeeAddress in the same class with AddClient. It doesn't make sense to me to call something like this Client.AddClient(). What is the best way to organize this?

Comment: Sounds like you want to use "procedural code" as opposed to "object-oriented". The hallmark of procedural code is precisely that methods are separate from data structures.

Comment: I understand that you are saying that it doesn't make sense to have a collection-related method on the element class (makes more sense to place it on the collection class instead); but we may need a bit more info if we are to provide sensible answers - so can you expand a little? E.g., what do you mean by "entity"? Are you talking about DDD entities, or something else, like ORM entities (e.g. Entity Framework in C#)? Are these classes auto-generated? Why are these methods on them currently? Add in any other info you think may be relevant.

Comment: @FilipMilovanović Let's say I want to make console application. Client and Employee would be separate classes with properties like ID, Name, Address etc... I also need to perform CRUD operations on instances of these classes, like adding, removing or editing employee and client so I would need AddClient(), RemoveClient() etc. methods. My question is where is it appropriate in a code to put these methods? I don't think it makes sense to put AddClient() method in Client class. Should I create new class like ClientManager and put those methods in there?

Comment: What are you adding the client to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to implement something like the DDD Repository Pattern. I suggest reading this article that talks about how to do this in C#.

https://www.infoworld.com/article/3107186/how-to-implement-the-repository-design-pattern-in-c.html

In short, each entity in your program will have a Repository to worry about persistence operations like CRUD and more.

```cs
ClientsRepository.Add(Client);
EmployeesRepository.Add(Employee);
```

This is a great start!